# I am getting Error in NodeJs NodeMailer with Express Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is My JS code where I want to send an email through Nodemailer. I have added the `nodemailer` dependency in my `package.json` but even though I am getting an error in the console.

```
var express = require('express');
var a = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var randomize = require('randomatic');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

server = require('http').createServer(app);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'official@gmail.com',
        pass: 'admin'
    }
});
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'official@gmail.com',
    to: 'akshay@digiasap.com',
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: 'That was easy!'
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
server.listen(8999, function (req, res) {
    console.log("blockaim Server started !")
});
```

This is my error console

```
3|blockaim | SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
3|blockaim |     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
3|blockaim |     at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
3|blockaim |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
3|blockaim |     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
3|blockaim |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
3|blockaim |     at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
3|blockaim |     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
3|blockaim |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/blockaim/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js:3:16)
3|blockaim |     at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
3|blockaim |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: when are you getting this error? At a time of staring or when you trigger some action

Comment: at starting time

Comment: Fixed some grammar mistakes and improved the formatting.

Comment: It says that you have an unexpected token. It looks like it says that `...`  is the unexpected token, and that is the token that is used for the spread-syntax. What version of node are you using? I suspect that you are using a too old one, that doesn't have support for the new syntax.